# CActiveDataProvider with condition value enum

Tags: php, yii

i have databse field usertype with enum('0','1'), default 1
While using CActiveDataProvider() with condition value enum it produce reverse rows.
        $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('ClubMember',array(
                     'criteria'=>array(
                            'condition'=>'usertype=1',
                        ),
                ));

This produce all the row except usertype=1, i.e. produce all row with usertype=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('ClubMember', array( 
    'criteria'=>  array(
       'condition'=>'usertype = "1"'
 )));
```

Its mean that you should use string as value in ENUM, not int